# Update Facebook AdAccount via API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to update the payment id on my ad accounts, Is there a way to do this via the API?

Code:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                    CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/act_$account_id",
                    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                        'funding_source' => $payment_id,
                        'access_token' => $access_token
                    )
                ));
```

Getting the following Error: Either the object you are trying to access is not visible to you or the action you are trying to take is restricted to certain account types.
Permissions Error: 200

I am using a system_admin token with all permission, and also tried creating a token with admin permissions, still get the same error.

Reading through the API I can't find any examples of updating an Ad Account.

Is there a way to update the payment (funding_source) id through the API?

Thanks,

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can update the funding_id on the Ad Account endpoint. Look at the parameter list of 3rd Update example in documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account

Comment: Yeah, Just had the facebook support team get back to me and it is not possible. Thanks